# ArcObjects Geoprocessing Failures

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, vb.net

I am working on launching the GenerateNearTable using the ArcObjects Assembly method.  I have the advanced license (10.1), so the tool is available.  The code to launch geoprocessing is:

```
   Private Sub generateNearTable(ByRef FeatureLayer)

    'Grab the feature class for the GP tool
    Dim lcount As Long = 10
    Dim closest As Boolean = False

    'Setup the geoprocessor
    Dim gp As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor
    Dim neartable As GenerateNearTable = New GenerateNearTable()


    neartable.in_features = FeatureLayer
    neartable.near_features = FeatureLayer
    neartable.out_table = "C:\Users\jlaura\Desktop\test4" ' Hard code to test.
    neartable.closest = closest
    neartable.closest_count = lcount 'This should be a parameter

    Dim addtomap As Boolean = gp.AddOutputsToMap
    gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", "C:\Users\jlaura\Desktop\test")
    gp.TemporaryMapLayers = False
    gp.AddOutputsToMap = False

    Try
        gp.Execute(neartable, Nothing)
        returnmessages(gp)
    Catch ex As Exception
        returnmessages(gp)
    End Try


End Sub
```

This is causing an error 99999.  The results are being returned to the results tab, so I am able to double click on the failed tool and run it successfully via ArcMap.  New to ArcObjects, so I'm definitely missing something obvious.

1. Do I need to check out a license like I would with ArcPy?
2. Am I parameterizing in a strange way?
3. Do I need to pass the dataset (IDataset) instead of the featureclass? #This failed when I tried it, but perhaps I missed something...

As an extension (that I can open as a new question if people think it is too disconnected) - to programatically set the output table, can I generate an empty, 'fieldless' standalone table and let the tool handle writing.

Updated Code:

```
Private Sub generateNearTable(ByVal distlayer, ByVal knn, ByVal DistanceTableOut)

    Dim FeatureLayer = GetFLayerByName(distlayer)
    Dim NearFeatureLayer = GetFLayerByName(distlayer) 'Fails if I use this.

    'Setup Params
    Dim lcount As Long = knn
    Dim closest As Boolean = False

    'Setup the geoprocessor
    Dim gp As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor
    Dim genneartable As GenerateNearTable = New GenerateNearTable()

    'Setup the Gp Environment
    Dim addtomap As Boolean = gp.AddOutputsToMap
    gp.TemporaryMapLayers = False
    gp.AddOutputsToMap = True 'Add the derived table to the map doc.
    gp.OverwriteOutput = True

    'Set Params
    genneartable.in_features = FeatureLayer
    genneartable.near_features = "C:\Users\jlaura\Desktop\Zunil\Zunil_secondaries_proj.shp"
    genneartable.out_table = DistanceTableOut
    genneartable.closest = closest
    genneartable.closest_count = lcount 'This should be a parameter

    'Execute
    Try
        gp.Execute(genneartable, Nothing)
        If gp.MessageCount > 0 Then
            For count As Integer = 0 To gp.MessageCount - 1
                MsgBox(gp.GetMessage(count), MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Working")
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

EDIT:

I am doing something wrong with the feature layer inputs.  By hard coding the path to the shapefiles I am able to successfully run the tool.  Back to the drawing board, re: featurelayer access.

EDIT2: The tools runs properly if the featurelayer is passed for the `in_features` and hard coded for the near_features.  In this case should I be reaccessing the feature layer from the input?

Comment: Have you tried registering an events listener, as described [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59889/59)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** (for the sake of others in a similar situation):

There are a few things you should be checking:

1) You're passing in a string for the `neartable.closest_count` variable when it requires a Long data type. Try this:

```
Dim lCount as Long = 10
neartable.closest_count = lCount
```

Also, the `neartable.closest` variable is being passed a String when it expects a Boolean (ALL = True).

2) Are you sure what you are passing in is actually an IFeatureLayer?

3) Why are you getting the FeatureClass from the FeatureLayer if you're never using that variable?

4) Your input features and near features are the same - is this what you want?

5) You might consider setting all of the GeoProcessor properties, especially the EnvironmentValue:

```
GP.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", "C:\workspacepathgoeshere")
```

6) An Events Listener (as mentioned by Kirk) can provide important information

7) Does the output table that you are trying to create already exist?

Comment: Altered the code.  I'm still getting error code 99999 (extra helpful).  Visual Studio is returning `A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.dll`  Any thoughts?  I'm on 10.1.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some additional things you should be checking.

Comment: Double check all of your inputs - you're passing in two strings when the GP expects a Long and a Boolean.

Comment: To answer the questions: (1) Made the change. (2) Yes. (3) I removed that line.  I tested both FC and FL. (4) Yes, This is generating a KNN table. (5) Done. (6) Implementing now.  I am still seeing the same error, so I'll dig into Kirk's link to look under the hood.

Comment: I made a quick edit that you might have missed - have you double checked both the input Long and Boolean that were being passed strings?

Comment: Checked immediately after your last post.  I notice that the Arc run of the tool turns the inputs into a list of featurelayers, while I am passing a single feature layer.  Passing a list of IFeatureLayers does not work on my end though. (7) - No.  If it does, I get a meaningful error.

Comment: Can you edit your first post and include your updated code underneath the original?

Comment: It looks like it comes down to your input FeatureLayer - have you attempted to hard code the path to this file? If this works you may have to consider how you are handling the passing of variables.

Comment: see my edit.  I just did this.

Answer (score 1):

I recently dealt with a similar problem; I wanted to pass an SDE layer as .near_features and it only worked when I passed the layer's path string.  Talked to the Esri Support and they came back a few days later and said it was a bug.

*Bug number: #NIM102924
Synopsis:  Generate Near table  geoprocessing tool s "Near Features" parameter doesn't accept FeatureLayer objects when passed from SDE.*

A way to work around it until they fix the bug is to pass the layer's name.

```
ILayer layer = //your layer;
generateNearTable.near_features = layer.name;
```

This worked for me.